# Make the keys of a map into a type without having to duplicate all the keys in a type union declaration?

Tags: typescript

In the code below I want to use the Keys type to type the parameter `a`. I am duplicating the keys "first", "second", "third" to achieve this. Can I achieve the same thing without duplicating the keys?

```
type Keys = "first" | "second" | "third";

const someMap = new Map<Keys, string>([
  ["first", "yes, master"],
  ["second", "what do you want?"],
  ["third", "poke, poke, poke - is that all you do?"],
]);

function func(a: Keys) {
  console.log(someMap.get(a));
}
```